# Is it possible to specify attribute names when creating an instance of namedtuple?

Tags: python

To create and use named tuple in Python, generally it's like this:

```
MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'])  
new_tuple = MyTuple('Bob', 'John', 'Tom')
```

Is there a way to specify attributes when creating the instance?

For example, I'd like to do something like:

```
new_tuple = MyTuple(attr1='Bob', attr2='John', attr3='Tom') # this does NOT work.
```

The only goal of this is to add readability in my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Works perfectly for me ...

Comment: Can you show the error you're getting? It works for me both in python 3.4 and 2.7.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake...I was doing using only one attribute instead of using them for the 3 values. I'm gonna delete the question it is useless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will technically work and is semi-self-documenting:

```
new_tuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'])('Bob', 'John', 'Tom')
```

Of course, you're creating a new class each time, which is inefficient. So you could write a helper function to do it with keywords as you want:

```
def nt_from_kws(cls, **kw):
    return cls(*(kw[k] for k in cls._fields))
```

Usage:

```
MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'])
new_tuple = nt_from_kws(MyTuple, attr1=1, attr2=2, attr3=3)
```

For even more fun, write a substitute `namedtuple` factory that adds a `from_kws` classmethod to the generated class:

```
from collections import namedtuple

@classmethod
def from_kws(cls, **kw):
    return cls(*(kw[k] for k in cls._fields))

def namedtuple(name, fields, namedtuple=namedtuple):
     nt = namedtuple(name, fields)
     nt.from_kws = from_kws
     return nt
```

Usage:

```
MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'])
new_tuple = MyTuple.from_kws(attr1=1, attr2=2, attr3=3)
```